# Is there a way to farm mushrooms?

Tags: dont-starve

Is there any way to transplant mushrooms to a different location?

I know if you dig them you get two caps, but they do not grow back.

Is there a different way to transport them so you can put them near your base?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to plant either [mushrooms](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Mushrooms) or [mushtrees.](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Tree#Mushtree)

Answer (score 0):

Update: there **is** now a way to farm them since 13th October 2016, brand new and only in the open `A new Reign` beta, with a [Mushroom Planter](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/69479-a-new-reign-update-log/?page=1) (Scroll to the third update, Arts and Crafts). Although this is somewhat disputed in the community since it might encourage turtling in your base even more